# Receiving bytes from Socket with java

Tags: java, sockets

i have searched a lot but i couldn't receive bytes from Socket using java also i have a jprogressbar i couldn't update it while receiving bytes to set the value 
so i've tried this code:

```
    private void jTextField1KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
   if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
       String az = jTextField1.getText();


       if(az.contains("1")){
            String hh = WorkSpace.jTextField1.getText();
            Socket so = new Socket();
            InputStream is = null;
            ProgressMonitorInputStream pmis = null;
            int buffer;
    try {
        so.getInputStream();
        buffer = so.getReceiveBufferSize();
        WorkSpace.jProgressBar1.setValue(buffer);
        WorkSpace.jEditorPane1.setPage("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + hh );

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }

       }
```

please can any body say what's wrong in my code and thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please make sure to properly format your code and say waht exactly is not working and what exactly you have tried. As for your question: you do not assign `so.getInputStream()` so you can't read anything.

Comment: At no point to you call any methods on the Socket's InputStream.  You're not getting any bytes because you're not asking for any.  You're also setting your progress bar's value to the size of the receive buffer, which never changes.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many wrong things with your code. I suggest you read the [Java tutorial about sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).